# Notifications in JavaFX 14

Tags: java, javafx

I know I can create a notification with

```
Notifications notificationBuilder = Notifications.create()
                .title(title)
                .text(content)
                .hideAfter(Duration.seconds(31536000))
                .position(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT)
                .onAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent a) {
                        //
                    }
                });

        notificationBuilder.showInformation();
```

But in IntelliJ (JDK 11 and JavaFX 14)
I can't find the class Notifications.
How can I create a notification in JavaFX 14?

Comment: Because it doesn't look like it's part of either one.  Only matching class I could find for this code is https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html, which is part of the ControlsFX project.  Here is the dependency for whatever build tool you are using: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx

Comment: Thanks, I thought its part of JavaFX

Comment: Package names for classes that are part of JavaFX will begin `javafx.`, so if you have existing code that uses classes that are not showing up in a different context, you can check the import statements to determine where those classes came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because it doesn't look like it's part of either one. Only matching
> class I could find for this code is
> [controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/…](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html), which is part of the
> ControlsFX project. Here is the dependency for whatever build tool you
> are using: [mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx)

– ajc2000